# Missing Asp.Net Session when using VLC Web plugin via embed tag

Tags: plugins, embed, vlc, asp.net-session

I have created a class in C# Asp.Net that acts as an `IHttpHandler` for handling some special requests in order to get Videos in the form of streams, retrieved from MS SQL Server 2008 database.
From front end I am using VLC Player's web plugin to request these Video streams using an embed tag like following:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
 width="840" height="472" name="vlcPlayerExtraFeatures"
 id="vlcPlayerExtraFeatures" target="http://my-pc/MyWebApp/file.ivd?VideoID=123"
 autoplay="true" windowless="true" bgcolor="#000000" />
   <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
   codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
   </object>
```

In my IHttpHandler class in *ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)* method, very first of all I check for the user's Asp.Net Session from "context" parameter like so:

```
if (context.Session["LoggedinUser"] == null) {
    //do bla bla bla
}
```

Issue is: Using VLC player web plugin, `context.Session["LoggedinUser"]` always comes as `null`.
If I request the same file using Windows media player web plugin, I do get mentioned session information but not with VLC.

If this some kind of issue with VLC media player?

Answer (score 0):

As per my finding, using VLC web plugin, you have no way accessing your Asp.Net session on server.
I have but done another workaround. In the code behind of page holding VLC embed tag. Upon page load, the value of URL parameter of VLC embed tag is appended a bypass token in the form of:

```
<OBJECT id="vlc" width="840" height="472" 
CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="http://mysite.com/video.ivd?videoId=myvideo1234&videoToken=some_token_with_expiry_date" />
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True" />
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True" />
<PARAM NAME="ShowControls" value="True" />
</OBJECT>
```

Note: The querystring part in this Url is shown here unencrypted but on actual page it comes as encrypted (done actually in page_load method).

When VLC requests the video from my custom IHttp handler,  the querystring part is decrypted in the handler and validity of token is evaluated from the supplied video token's expiry date. If it is still valid, video is streamed to the client otherwise request is denied, so that client might not make use of this Url for an indefinite period of time.

Well this is a workaround that worked for my case. May be somebody else have a more better approach than this.